# Application crashes by tap on UITextField in ios

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, uitextfield, chat

My application crashes when I tap on `UITextField` . When I present `controller` first time it works fine but when I dismiss `controller` and than present again tap on `UITextField`, give execution bad access error.

I know that this error comes when we access object which is already release but I check textfiled delegate method `textfileddidbeginedit` call and `keyboarswillappear` notification call but after that I get `exac_bad_access` error 
Please help i try to find solution every where but not get exect solution

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the crash console message ?

Comment: nothing just got debugger pointer on main class with message execution bad access

Comment: Check wheather you are connected class to your ViewController in StoryBoard

Comment: yes i check view controller attached i make all login screen in same controller just navigate view up and down but get same error

Answer (score 0):

It simply indicates that your controller object is getting released. So if you try to access any object of you controller it will crash, so modify your code in such as way that controller object should not get release whenever you try to access the object inside it.

Comment: except touch uuitextfiled it performs all action not crash on touch button which are also in this controller every time i make new object of this controller

Comment: Oh then check the method of UITextfield?

Comment: OH thanks to tools provided by xcode "profiler" it tell me which thing is become zoombie